# Number of hadoop jobs per query

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm, hive

I am new to hive and I have been playing with it for sometime now. I dont know how the hive optimizer works, but basically I want to know the maximum number of hadoop jobs that hive will run, just to see where the bottleneck lies, I have tried queries on a single table with multiple levels of query nesting and I have never found a case where there are more than 2 hadoop jobs submitted to give me the result of the query. Can someone give me an example query where there are 2 hadoop jobs submitted by hive on that query.

I have a query with 2 levels of nesting and I was running it with 1 map/1 reduce, and the time taken was around 84s. I changed the mappers to 10 and reducers to 10 and the execution time increased to 89s.

```
Runtime usage:
Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 10
Job 1: Map: 5  Reduce: 1

Time taken: 89.306 seconds,
```

I suspect it must be because of JVM invocation time. Can someone tell me why this is the case? Also can the JVM's be reused in the same hadoop jobs? If yes, can the JVM's be shared across multiple hadoop jobs (Which is basically having a pool of JVM's preallocated for use with a map/reduce rather than spawning JVM's on demand?.).

Does hadoop provide such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any limit to the number of jobs a single hive query will run. I think I've seen up to 5 or so, but more than 2 is rare, I agree. There are a number of operations (joins, "distinct", "group by") that have to happen as part of their own shuffle-sort-reduce phase, so nesting many of those can cause many jobs. Contrast those to things like filters and UDFs, which can easily be tacked on to a map or reduce phase that was going to happen anyway. For example:

```
select a.z, max(b.s) from
(
  select distinct x, y, z from t1
) a join
(
  select x, sum(y) as s from t2 group by x
) b
on a.x = b.x
group by a.z
```

I would expect that to take four or so MR jobs.

For your second question, there are many things involved in the length of time it takes a hive query to run, so I can't say for sure what caused this performance behavior. 84s to 89s is definitely within normal fluctuations even if you hadn't changed anything about the settings. At that small of a job, most of that is overhead anyway.

JVM start up could be a factor, especially depending on how many task slots you have. As far as I know, JVMs cannot be shared across different mapreduce jobs, only across different tasks within a single job.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how I can get a single hadoop job to share JVM's in a hive query?